# CLion Go to definition keymap change

Tags: ide, clion, jetbrains-ide

The default shortcut for going to definition is `Ctrl+Alt+B`. How can I change it, as I haven't found it in `Settings->Keymap` ?

Answer (score 1):

Found it in `Settings` > `Keymap` as `GotoImplementation`.

Comment: Settings > Keymap. Then in the right pane tree Main Menu -> Navigate -> Goto by Reference Actions -> GotoImplementation